# Calendar Drop Down in PHP: keep selected value and re-use the function

Tags: php, mysql, list, function

I have found online the following PHP function on defining a calendar drop-down (in month/day/year format). The function is working fine, but I would like:

a) Keep the selected value for Month, Day and Year, so to be able to edit values easily (values are defined dynamically through a foreach loop), and

b) would like to re-use the function on multiple variables (so far, I am using it to define date of birth, but I would like to use the same function also on additional fields too).

The fact that the values for Month, Day and Year are defined dynamically is a little bit confusing me, and of course I am not fluent in functions definition yet. Any help would be greatly appreciated !

Here is the function:

```
function make_calendar_pulldowns() {

    // Make the months array:
    $months = array (1 => 'January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December');

    // Make the months pull-down menu:
    //echo '<p><label for="dob" style="font-family: Verdana, Arial; font-size: 1.0em; font-weight: 600; color: #595959; line-height: 1.9em;">Date of Birth</label></p>';
    echo '<select required="required" name="month" id="month" style="width: 33%; display: inline; float: left; margin-left: 1%; margin-right: 0%">';
    echo '<option selected value="">Month</option>\n';
    foreach ($months as $key => $value) {
        echo "<option value=\"$key\" >$value</option>\n";
    }
    echo '</select>';

    // Make the days pull-down menu:
    echo '<select required="required" name="day" id="day" style="width: 33%; display: inline; float: left; margin-left: 0%; margin-right: 0%" ;>';
    echo '<option selected value="">Day</option>\n';
    for ($day = 1; $day <= 31; $day++) {
        echo "<option value=\"$day\">$day</option>\n";
    }
    echo '</select>';

    // Make the years pull-down menu:
    echo '<select required="required" name="year" id="year" style="width: 33%; display: inline; float: left; margin-left: 0%; margin-right: 0%" ;>';
    echo '<option selected value="">Year</option>\n';
    for ($year = 1910; $year <= 2000; $year++) {
        echo "<option value=\"$year\">$year</option>\n";
    }
    echo '</select>';
```

Once values have been defined, I convert them to MySQL format with the following code:

```
// Validate the month.
if (is_numeric ($month)) {
    $dob = $month . '-';

} else {
    $action['result'] = 'error'; 
    array_push($text,'Please insert a valid Month for patient birth date');
}
// Validate the day.
if (is_numeric ($day)) {
    $dob .= $day . '-';

} else {
    $action['result'] = 'error'; 
    array_push($text,'Please insert a valid Day for patient birth date');
}
// Validate the year.
if (is_numeric ($year)) {
    $dob = $year . '-' . $month . '-' .  $day; // Set Birthdate in SQL format
```

Finally, I call the function in the form with the following code:

```
<!-- <p><label for="dob">Date of Birth <img src="../img/req.gif" alt="Required"</label></p>
<?php make_calendar_pulldowns(); ?> -->
```

Comment: So am I correct in thinking you want someone here to write this code for you? **This is not s free coding service** Can I suggest a quick read of this [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: ehmm...my apologies if I asked something inappropriate, actually I did not want someone to write the function for me (I have already worked on that), just to show me the way to modify it so to make it re-usable. Anyhow, thanks for the suggestion, will take a look at that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually some parts of it are a bit off:

```
// Make the months array:
$months = array ('January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December');
// some months are a bit off, the keys are missing
// Should be something like this:

$months = array ('January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December');
$month_num = range(1, 12);
$months = array_combine($month_num, $months);
```

And the days are hardcoded, what about February 31?

The Years I guess should be okay.

Why not use a date picker (jQuery UI in particular) for this purpose instead?

```js
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd', // iso format
    });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<form method="POST">
  <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" name="date"></p>
  <input type="submit" name="submit1" />
</form>
```

Then in PHP, just call it like a normal `$_POST`

```
if(isset($_POST['submit1'])) {
    $date = $_POST['date'];
}
```

More API Info: http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Comment: Thank you for the help. I also believe the best way to approach this is Javascript / JQuery, the thing is I do not know enough on that to solve the problem, so I thought to stick with PHP till I would have learned more on JQuery, but I will look at the link you have suggested and will implement datepicker (If I will be able to)...again, thanks a lot for the snippet, really helpful !

Comment: @Diego yes i would definitely recommend going this route, so that you don't need to code the necessary days, leap years, etc. by hand. actually what you really need to do is just use this way, and the textbox value already writes the proper date and voila its okay now, anyways, im glad this gave some insight.

Comment: Ok, I have worked on your suggestion (actually, just a little bit) and it is working like a champ....THANKS A MILLION appreciated !

Comment: @Diego yeah actually its a little bit stress free using this one, im glad  this helped